# Apply function across rows

Tags: r, apply

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

I have a `df` with 4 rows and 25 columns, and I want to make a calculation across all rows with the following formula:

```
(df['next column'] - df['current column'])/df['current column']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
(df[-1] - df[-ncol(df)])/df[-ncol(df)]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:25, 5, 5))
```

Comment: always quick and efficient :D

Comment: Wouldn't you want the denominator to be `df[-ncol(df)]`?

Comment: @Dason Thank you for that.  You are a great guy!

Comment: @user2105555  If akrun's solution worked for you, it would be good to accept the answer.

Comment: There should be an auto-accept answer whenever akrun responds.

Comment: @user2105555  Thank you for encouraging others to follow the SO guidelines so that it won't get into the unanswered queue.